# EF подгрузка вложенных коллекций

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity

Приложение asp.net core. Имеется следующий список моделей:

```
public class Year
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ex. 2014-2015, 2018-2019

    public bool IsSemestr { get; set; }

    public int PartOfYear { get; set; }

    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string NameGroup { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Debt { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ExamType { get; set; }

    public double Credits { get; set; }

    public double Hours { get; set; }

    public string Lecture { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }

    public string DateDebt { get; set; }
}
```

А также следующий контекст БД:

```
public class UniversityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Year> Years { get; set; }


    public UniversityContext(DbContextOptions<UniversityContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

В контроллер передается имя студента, которого необходимо найти в БД. И тут появляется проблема. Данные в БД присутствуют, я смотрел в обозревателе SQL, но они не подгружаются, загружается только класс Year, а все остальные вложенные коллекции равны null. Как исправить проблему, подтягиваю данные с БД в контроллере следующим кодом:

```
   public string Get(string discipline, string student, string group, string time)
    {
        if(student != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Year> fYear = context.Years;


            View("byName.cshtml", fYear.First().Groups[0].Students[0]);
        }
        return "hi";
    }
```

[image: Groups == null хотя их там 35 штук]

Comment: Чтобы работала ленивая загрузка, свойство должно быть помечено `virtual`.

Comment: Я пометил и все равно не работает.

Comment: в представленном коде свойство `Groups` класса `Year` не помечено как `virtual`